# FreeAgent oAuth2 can't update contact using Light PHP wrapper

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I’m having problems creating a new contact in FreeAgent.

I’m using the Light PHP wrapper for the OAuth 2.0 protocol and have managed to successfully set up oAuth2. I can connect to FreeAgent and successfully retrieve a list of customers. So far, so good. The problem I’ve got is sending data back the other way, i.e. creating a new contact in FreeAgent.

Here’s some code I’ve tried:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/OAuth2/Client.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/OAuth2/GrantType/IGrantType.php');

$client = new OAuth2\Client($clientid, $secret);

$params = json_encode(array('contact' => array('first-name' => $firstname_unencrypted, 'last-name' => $surname_unencrypted)));

$response = $client->fetch("/contacts", $params, "POST", array('User-Agent' => 'MyApp', 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-type' => 'application/json'));

var_dump($response);
```

The var_dump returned shows:

```
array(3) {
  ["result"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["content_type"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

I’m pretty sure I’m doing something silly. I’ve tried sending in XML instead of JSON. I’ve tried using just a single array of params rather than the array in an array I’ve got in the sample. I’m going round in circles!

If someone could give me a little nudge in the right direction, I’d be eternally grateful!

Comment: I'm using CURL and am now making some progress with this, but still getting an error. I'll investigate further and if I find a solution, I'll post it here...

Comment: Yep, CURL worked fine. Should've thought of that before. Stand down!!

Answer (score 0):

Sample code that worked:

```
            $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
                     <contact>
                      <first-name>$firstname_unencrypted</first-name>
                      <last-name>$surname_unencrypted</last-name>
                    </contact>";

            if ($sandbox || $demo)
                $ch = curl_init('https://api.sandbox.freeagent.com/v2/contacts');
            else
                $ch = curl_init('https://api.freeagent.com/v2/contacts');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Authorization: Bearer '.$freeagentaccesstoken,
                'Content-Type: application/xml',
                'Accept: application/json',
                'User-Agent: MyApp',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml))
            );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

            //execute post
            $result=json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
            $freeagenturl=$result['contact']['url'];
            curl_close($ch);
```